# php date.timezone problem

Tags: php, date, clock, setting

i am storing member's created date using the [time()](http://id.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) function, and echo them back using [strftime()](http://id.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) and the [date()](http://id.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function, but it doesnt display the right time information

my code is :

```
date("d-m-Y H:i:s", $member->created)
strftime("%Y-%m-%d",$member->created)
```

it should have displayed this:

```
17-11-2010 14:42
```

rather than:

```
17-11-2010 23:45
```

now, i have change my php.ini date.timezone configuration into my current time zone which is "Asia/Jakarta", yet nothing change. i have also try to set them manually inside my code using

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Jakarta");
```

what did i miss ? please help me

Regards

EDIT:

according to [Noodles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/227577/noodles), i need to check the server's clock setting, so i did using the 
hwclock command, and it turns out that the clock setting is not right, since it displayed

```
Thu 18 Nov 2010 02:07:25 AM WIT  -0.931691 seconds
```

while it should have been

```
Wed 17 Nov 2010 05:04:ss PM
```

now, how can i syncronize this setting into my timezone ??

Edit: i have manage to change the clock setting using

```
date -s "HH:MM:SS"
hwclock --systohc
```

thanks for pointing me out [Noodles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/227577/noodles)

case is closed i guess :D

thanks again guys

Comment: Did you restart Apache when you changed php.ini?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your server's clock is set correctly? It would seem weird that the minutes would change. At the most I'd expect the hours to change if it was a different time zone, but not minutes.

Comment: i am not sure about the server's clock setting, how can i check this ?? thanks